# Alt+Tab behaves like Alt is sticking (but it is not)

Tags: windows-7, keyboard

Sometimes, when I press Alt+Tab and then release, the window select menu stays up until I chose a window with mouse or press Enter. Just like if I wouldn't let Alt key go (but I do). Anyone has an idea why this could be the case?

1. My keybord is brand new (3 days old). Also I opened screen keyboard and see when Alt/Ctrl/Shift/Win keys are pressed and when they are not. So **I'm sure none of those 4 keys are sticking by any mechanical reason**.
2. The behavior is "localy stable". I.e. it works many times in a row. And then (when I forget about it) it behaves normaly many times in a row.
3. I doesn't it when switching from specific windows. But those specific windows are different each time. I mean when it starts to "stick" it sticks all the time for some windows A,B,C and doesn't stick for D,E,F; then it stop to stick and starts again in a while and now it sticks for A,E,F and doesn't stick for B,C,D.
4. It behaves in the same way with left and right Alt.
5. I use SharpKeys to remap control keys. Caps -> Left Ctrl, Left Alt -> Left Ctrl, Left Ctrl -> Left Win, Left Win->Right Alt.
6. I have sticky-keys disabled.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have discovered that that happended only when a top window is in foreing keyboard layout (I've tried Greek, Russian, German). When I switched layout of the top window to English I could use AltTab normally.

Then I was able to check if this disappears when I turn off SharpKeys (thanks to @JaredT for the hint). And I've found out that the problem was that my Right Alt on my keyboard is actually Alt Gr. So when I used SharpKeys **I actually used AltGr+Tab instead of Alt+Tab**. Once I've rebinded to use Left Alt instead of Right everything started to work fine.

So I guess AltGr makes Tab to mean something different when you use layout different from English.

Comment: `AltGr` is basically `Ctrl+Alt` on Windows. For example with Polish layout the normal way to type letter 'ą' is to press `AltGr+A` and everyone types it like that, but `Ctrl+Alt+A` works too. Congratulations on figuring it out yourself!

Answer (score 3):

What you're describing is expected behavior for <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>.

> I use SharpKeys to remap control keys. **Caps -> Left Ctrl**

After this remapping you have <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> directly below <kbd>Tab</kbd>. I guess you're accidentally pressing <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd> along with <kbd>Tab</kbd>.

Answer (score 0):

Any keyboard input encryption such as Sophos Keyboard Guard in Sophos Home Premium (or Zemana, GuardedID, KeyScrambler or any Anti-keylogger) can cause ALT-TAB delays.

https://support.home.sophos.com/hc/en-us/articles/360021845231-Safe-Online-Banking-Keylogger-protection-feature-compatibility

Answer (score 0):

In my case (on Win10), simply hitting <kbd>Capslock</kbd> once solved this issue. It was off to begin with, so this turned <kbd>Capslock</kbd> on. I hit it again to turn it back off with no further issues.

I have no idea what the initial cause was. I verified that in other contexts, the OS didn't act as though <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> or <kbd>Alt</kbd> was pressed. Sticky keys was off, and I don't have any keys remapped (I have a few AutoHotkey macros, but none use <kbd>Alt</kbd>, <kbd>Tab</kbd>, or <kbd>Capslock</kbd>.).

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem today.  For me, it turned out that it's an idiotic MS-Win 10 setting under System - Multitasking.  Under "Alt + Tab", drop the box "Pressing Alt + Tab shows", and pick "Open windows only".  I don't use MS-Edge, and I don't care to, it wasn't open, but somehow this setting was causing Alt-Tab to stick.  It seems OK, until tomorrow's UI debacle, anyway :-) Big shout out to MakeUseOf for this hack, in the article "How to Customize the Alt + Tab Switcher in Windows 10".